# How to upgrade php version 5.3.X to 5.4.X without changing Apache and Mysql in xampp

Tags: php

I had searched but i could not get the proper guide.I just upgraded Phpmyadmin of my xampp to latest version,but it seems difficult to upgrade the "php version" of my xampp,since i am using php version 5.3.x.Is there any possible solution to upgrade the latest php version only without upgrading to a newer xampp ?

Comment: Why do you not want to update XAMPP? If you backup your configuration files, and your databases, you shouldn't have a problem upgrading. Either way, a solution I see would be to take all the PHP-related files from the newer XAMPP and copy to the older directory, and also make sure all the config files point to the new PHP

Comment: Have you tried installing the php version of your choice from [here](http://us3.php.net/downloads.php) into the folder `your/xampp/php`?

Comment: i am new to linux and i installed xampp in /opt.So in which folder  do i have paste the new php version? In /opt/lampp or in any other folder?